# sin v/s sinf function in C

Tags: c, math, visual-c++, floating-point, trigonometry

I am trying to use the `sinf` function in my C Program but it gives me an undefined reference error under MSVC 6.0, however `sin` works fine.

This make me curious to find the difference between `sin` and `sinf`.

What is the logical difference between `sin` and `sinf` ?

How can I implement my own `sinf` functionality?

Comment: Using a float function to compute the sine is a sinf.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sin` takes a double and returns a double - `sinf` takes a float and returns a float.

In other words `sin` is double precision and `sinf` is single precision.

If you're using an old compiler that doesn't have sinf you can implement it as:

`#define sinf(x) (float)sin((double)(x))`

Answer (score 3):

sin takes a double and returns a double and is defined by ANSI C.  sinf isn't.

Comment: `sinf()` is not standard in C89.  It _is_ standard in C99.

Answer (score 3):

`sinf()` was added to C in C99, which Microsoft Visual C++ does not fully support (even so, Visual C++ 6 was released before C99 was standardized).

You can use the `sin()` function, which takes a `double` (`sinf()` takes a `float`).