# Sinf - Does it exist in C++?

Tags: c++, math.h, trigonometry

I was curious to know whether or not the `sinf` function existed in C++ through including `math.h`.

When viewing my auto-completion in Qt Creator, it doesn't appear to pop up. It makes me wonder if, for some reason, it was taken out. A Google search doesn't seem to pop up with many references either; most of them are in reference to straight C.

So, can this be confirmed?

Comment: Since C++ supports overloading, it's generally just named `sin`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841639/sin-v-s-sinf-fucntion-in-c

Answer (score 5):

It depends on which version of the standard your implementation supports.

The `sinf` function did not exist in the 1990 ISO C standard (nor did `sind`).  The only `sin` function was `sin`, which takes a `double` argument and returns a `double` result.  (The "Future Library Directions" section, 7.13, does say that math functions with names suffixed with `f` or `l` are reserved.)

The `sinf` and `sind` functions were added in the 1999 ISO C standard (C99).

The 2003 edition of the ISO C++ standard says, in section 17.4.1.2 [lib.headers]:

> Except as noted in clauses 18 through 27, the contents of each header
>   *cname* shall be the same as that of the corresponding header *name.h*, as
>   specified in ISO/IEC 9899:1990 Programming Languages C (Clause 7), or
>   ISO/IEC:1990 Programming Languages—C AMENDMENT 1: C Integrity, (Clause
>   7), as appropriate,  as if by inclusion.

The 2011 ISO C++ standard (at least the N3290 draft) includes the following as normative references:

- ISO/IEC 9899:1999, *Programming languages — C*
- ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.1:2001(E), *Programming languages — C, Technical Corrigendum 1*
- ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.2:2004(E), *Programming languages — C, Technical Corrigendum 2*
- ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.3:2007(E), *Programming languages — C, Technical Corrigendum 3*

So a C++ implementation that conforms to a standard earlier that C++11 needn't provide `sinf`.  It's not clear whether it's *permitted* to do so, but since all standard prior to C++11 are officially obsolete, it's probably a moot question.

It's probably common for pre-C++11 implementations to provide `sinf()` and friends as a (possibly non-conforming) extension.

Practically, you can always just call `sin()`; in most cases the argument and result will be implicitly converted from `float` to `double` and from `double` to `float`.  There might (or might not) be some loss of efficiency.

Comment: "Practically, you can always just call sin()"

What if you're using, say a Cortex-M4F whose FPU only supports single-precision operations. Then you'll want to be explicit and use `sinf`.

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut If the argument is of type `float`, the overloaded `sin` is equivalent to `sinf`.

Comment: Ah, missed this is a C++ Q. @KeithThompson

Answer (score 1):

All C functions exist in C++, unless their header files take the *explicit* step of checking whether it's a C++ compiler and hiding the definition in that case.

So yes, you may use `sinf` from C++ code just like you would from C. In fact, you can (with a few very narrow exceptions) write C90 code and pass it through `g++`, calling it C++.

EDIT: `sinf`, at least on my machine, is not exposed by `math.h` unless one of the following is `#define`ed before including that header:

```
_BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600
|| _ISOC99_SOURCE || _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L
```

So in C++ code you might need to set one of those preprocessor defines in order to get the prototype.

Comment: Funny that you mention C90. `sinf` wasn't added to the standard until C99.

Comment: @CodyGray ... or you could get it because it's a BSD function. But I'll add a note on this *particular* function.